# Send message to thin clients trough angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, server, alert, message

I have a web application developed with angularJS. There is a form where workplace accidents are saved to the database. When a new record is saved I need to send information to all the computers on the network. Most of them are thin clients related to a terminal server. My web application won't be running ot the clients. Only an alert/message should be shown there, like "New accident was recorded.".

I couldn't find which technology should I use. Any suggestions please?

Thank you in advance!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There has to be server part of the application that takes care of saving data to database. In that function which saves data, at the end you could create a mailing list of target users (or predefined group of receivers) and create a mail that will be sent with message you want em to receive.
Popping message boxes on network computers is far from any practical solution.
So you don't need any special technology, you already have all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Mladen!

I already have a function sending mail to some predefined users. But there are a lot of client machines in which   can't send/receive mails... So I have to warn them in some other way.

I'm researching now node.js child_process spawn in order to run command prompt. But couldn't figure out yet how to use node.js.

Thank you again!

Edit: For those who search a similar solution:

With the following line I managed to pop up a message on my computer from javaScript:

java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c msg userID msg_text");

But that is not exactly what I need. I will write here again when I find the solution.